# Is the king actually in check if the attacking piece cannot be moved?

Tags: check

Black was in a position to take a white bishop with the king.  The white bishop was protected by a white knight.  However, if the white knight was moved it would expose the white king to the black queen.

Thus, is the king actually in check if the attacking piece (white knight) cannot be moved?
Or,
Can the king move into check if the attacking piece (white knight) cannot move?

Thank you.

Comment: See a similar question [here](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/illegal-move-can-put-a-king-in-check).

Comment: One way to reason out such situations is as follows. Earlier in history,killing the opponents king was considered to be the victory. Hence as per this rule, technically, a player has won the game if he has killed the opponent's king and the game ends there. It does not matter that the player's own king could have been killed in the next move. Today, in contemporary chess, checkmate is considered an elegant way to end the game. But the same reasoning applies.

Answer (score 5):

Still considered in check. [FIDE handbook](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=124&view=article) from the WCF website.

> 3.9
>   The king is said to be 'in check' if it is attacked by one or more of the opponent's pieces, **even if such pieces are constrained from moving to that square because they would then leave or place their own king in check.** No piece can be moved that will either expose the king of the same colour to check or leave that king in check.