# Simultaneous check

Tags: rules

My pawn is pinned by the enemy bishop, however if I push the pinned pawn 1 space my rook would then put the opposing king in check resulting in a simultaneous check with my opponent to move next   Can I move my pinned pawn in that situation?

Comment: In fact, there is a caveat about this question, taking into account the time control used in the game. See my answer here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/moving-king-into-check/22399#22399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Doing so would put you in check, and it would be the enemy's turn.

You can think of it this way, the enemy would have the first opportunity to take a king, so if the game was about taking kings, then you would lose in this situation.

You can never make a move that would allow the enemy to take your king, even if you put their king in check at the same time.