# Can my King take?

Tags: endgame, rules

ok so here is the issue I'm having... I am playing a correspondence game online and I came across a situation where I pinned my opponents rook against his King and in between his rook and my king is his pawn. if it's my turn can I take the pawn? there would be nothing in between my king and his rook but his rook would not be able to move because it is pinned against his king. let me know. thanks!

Comment: There's even more discussion at [illegal (?) move can put a king in check?](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/illegal-move-can-put-a-king-in-check).

Comment: no, because if you take the pawn, then your opponent will simply capture your king before you can capture his.

Comment: Are you able to attached a picture of your position. I would to be absolutely sure of the position before I respond. thanks.

Comment: And if you play online, you can actually just try to take with the king. The software should tell you it's an illegal move.