# Using a check-preventing piece to protect the checkmating piece

Tags: rules, checkmate, check, kings

Let's say that a piece is protecting my king from check, i.e. blocked or pinned. For example, my rook is in the way of my opponent's queen in checking my king. Can I checkmate their king with another piece, let's say my queen, if my check-preventing rook protects my queen, even though I could technically not move that rook?

Answer (score 5):

Yes- if they captured your queen, then it would count as them going into check:

(from [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/can-a-piece-pinned-to-my-king-put-the-opponents-king-in-check?rq=1), ironically listed as a "Related" question here)

> Besides making sense, it's also explicitly stated in the rules of the
> game:
>
> 3.9 The king is said to be 'in check' if it is attacked by one or more of the opponent's pieces, even if such pieces are constrained from
> moving to that square because they would then leave or place their own
> king in check. No piece can be moved that will either expose the king
> of the same colour to check or leave that king in check.
>
> Source: [Laws of Chess on the FIDE site](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=124&view=article)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I did not see the related question when i posted. Tah!